# datagridview cell null or empty

Tags: datagridview

to check datagridview cell for null  value or empty I have used the following code

```
 if (dgvPersonnelInfo.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value==null )
            {

            }
```

but it gives me error object reference not set to an instance of an object. Is there any one to help

Answer (score 0):

Try checking to see if dgvPersonnelInfo.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2] is null or not. If so then this will be the cause of your issue, as the code cannot find the value for an object that does not exist.